# g++ Conflicts appeared

Tags: gcc, g++

When I type:
g++ --version

in a console, I get the message:

```
The program 'g++' is currently not installed. 
You can install it by typing:

sudo apt install g++
```

But, when I type:

```
sudo apt install g++-4.8
```

(which is the version I want to install)

I get

```
g++ is already the newest version (4.8.5-4ubuntu2)
```

After the

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

I get

```
update-alternatives: error no alternatives for gcc
```

PS
I have used previously the command

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8
```

which I suspect is the cause of this inconsistency between the messages.

What can I do to have gcc-4.8 and g++-4.8 now installed properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your symbolic link correct? Is not `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8` (slash at beginning of first gcc path)?

Comment: @Redbob, I copied it wrong, I edited it.

Comment: What does `sudo update-alternatives --config gcc` give you please add to your question.

Comment: @George, I did so

Comment: what happens when you just go `sudo apt install g++` ?

Comment: @doug g++ is already the newest version (4.8.5-4ubuntu2)

Comment: Someone noticed that "g++-4.8 --version" might work, and it did work! Can someone explain me why? (I will edit the question)

Comment: `$ g++ --version` works fine here (on 16.04, I've no doubt it'll work in other releases), produces (truncated for comments), `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609` g++ is just a  dependency package that also installs a symlink

Answer (score 0):

You must link g++ as well

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8
```